# ImageMagick command slowness issue

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, image-processing, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick for some image processing in my web application (using Java as backend in Ubuntu OS), to identify CMYK colors from the images.

**Orginial Image :**

[image]

Procedure is as below for whole image :

First, I am separating four images in grayscale of CMYK :

```
convert IMG_1732.jpg -colorspace CMYK -negate -separate IMG_1732-sep.jpg
```

Result of Four images as below :

**Image 1 :**

[image]

**Image 2 :**

[image]

**Image 3 :**

[image]

**Image 4 :**

[image]

Then I am executing below commands to convert each from grayscale to C,M,Y,K color image :

```
convert IMG_1732-sep-0.jpg -channel C -combine IMG_1732-sep-00.jpg
```

**Result 1:**

[image]

```
convert IMG_1732-sep-1.jpg -channel M -combine IMG_1732-sep-11.jpg
```

**Result 2:**

[image]

```
convert IMG_1732-sep-2.jpg -channel Y -combine IMG_1732-sep-22.jpg
```

**Result 3:**

[image]

```
convert IMG_1732-sep-3.jpg -channel K -combine IMG_1732-sep-33.jpg
```

**Result 4:**

[image]

Problem is, it is taking too much time, image size is around more than 2-3 MB. Also, consuming more RAM and CPU as well.

- How can I optimize it? Is there any other option in ImageMagick or
  any other way?
- How can I know percentage of CYAN available in original image? Same as Magenta, Yellow and Black? Is it possible?

Comment: I understand the first command converts the image to CMYK, inverts the channels and separates them into 4 separate JPG files. I have no idea what the next 4 commands are trying to do? You say you want to *"find the CMYK in each"* but what does that mean? There will be no MY or K in the separate file that contains C. What will be the answer to your question - do you expect an image of something? four separate images of something? the means of some images? It is very unclear to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to have a color image for your number 4, if that was a channel separated from CMYK. All single channels will be grayscale. Also I cannot reproduce your exact colors. So either the image is different or changed or you have not told us all your processing steps.

Similar to Mark Setchell's command, I can write your command in one command line and get processing times of about 0.63 sec.

```
time convert image.jpg -colorspace cmyk -negate -separate \
\( -clone 0 -channel C -combine +write C.jpg \) \
\( -clone 1 -channel M -combine +write M.jpg \) \
\( -clone 2 -channel Y -combine +write Y.jpg \) \
\( -clone 3 -channel K -combine +write K.jpg \) \
null:

0.626s
```

C.jpg
[image]

M.jpg
[image]

Y.jpg
[image]

K.jpg
[image]

If you want smaller file sizes, then add -quality XX to each of the commands in parenthesis just before the +write. Or find some JPG optimizer tool to post process each resulting image. Imagemagick uses libjpeg, which may not be the most efficient compressor. I checked and your input and all my output results use -quality 95.

If I include -normalize to increase contrast, I can get closer to your results, but the processing time goes up to about 0.83 sec.

```
convert image.jpg -colorspace cmyk -negate -separate -normalize \
\( -clone 0 -channel C -combine +write C.jpg \) \
\( -clone 1 -channel M -combine +write M.jpg \) \
\( -clone 2 -channel Y -combine +write Y.jpg \) \
\( -clone 3 -channel K -combine +write K.jpg \) \
null:
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I know percentage of CYAN available in original image? Same as Magenta, Yellow and Black?

```
convert image.jpg -colorspace CMYK -format "%[fx:mean.c], %[fx:mean.m], %[fx:mean.y], %[fx:mean.k]\n" info:
```

**Output :** 0.0606194, 0.0598201, 0.0300933, 0.0748128

These values are fractions in the range 0 to 1. For percent, multiply each mean by 100. Kindly note the colon at the end is needed.

Comment: Cool - that's better. I knew I wasn't thinking straight :-)

Comment: Is there any way, to find out percentage of C, M, Y, K in generated four images?

Comment: You can just get the mean value of the image, I suppose, by `convert C.jpg -format "%[fx:100*mean] info:`. Or from your original image `convert input.jpg -colorspace CMYK -format "%[fx:mean.c], %[fx:mean.m], %[fx:mean.y], %[fx:mean.k]" info:`. You an add your -negate to the command, if you want so that the results match your negated resulting C.jpg, etc.

Comment: I mean, should I know from any image, how much percentage of `CYAN` available in original image? Same as Magenta, Yellow and Black? Your command generates a new image.

Comment: That command should not create a new image. It only writes the info: . Note the colon at the end is needed. `convert logo: -colorspace CMYK -format "%[fx:mean.c], %[fx:mean.m], %[fx:mean.y], %[fx:mean.k]\n" info:` returns only `0.0606194, 0.0598201, 0.0300933, 0.0748128` on my Mac OSX Sierra with IM 6.9.10.11 Q16. Those values are fractions in the range 0 to 1. If you want percent, multiply each mean by 100. What is your exact ImageMagick version and platform?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure of this, but have done some work and wanted to share it. I, or one of my StackOverflow buddies might come up with something better when we understand better, so I'll show what I have so far.

The slowness is probably coming from having to start 5 processes and having to read in JPEG images and decode them 5 times, so I want to use a single process and do it all in one go.

Here's what I have:

```
convert image.jpg -colorspace cmyk -separate -write MPR:orig                                             \
   +delete -colorspace gray -threshold 101% -write MPR:blackx3 -delete 0,1,2                             \
   \( MPR:orig -delete 1,2,3 MPR:blackx3           -set colorspace CMYK -combine -write C.jpg +delete \) \
   \( MPR:orig -delete 0,2,3 MPR:blackx3 -swap 0,1 -set colorspace CMYK -combine -write M.jpg +delete \) \
   \( MPR:orig -delete 0,1,3 MPR:blackx3 -swap 0,2 -set colorspace CMYK -combine -write Y.jpg +delete \) \
      MPR:orig -delete 0,1,2 K.jpg
```

I am sure that is a bit daunting, so I'll explain each line at a time...

**Line 1:** Load the original image, convert to CMYK colourspace and separate into 4 separate images, one with C, one with M, one with Y and one with K. Save all 4 of those images in a lump of RAM called `"orig"`.

**Line 2:** Delete the last channel on the stack, which was K, leaving C, M and Y. Make all of those 3 images fully black and save in a lump of memory named `"blackx3"` so I have three empty black channels for later.

**Line 3:** Reload the CMYK from RAM, delete MYK, leaving C, then load 3 empty black channels. We now have C, Black, Black, Black on our stack. Tell IM the 4 images on our stack are CMYK channels and combine them and write as `"C.jpg"`. Clean up.

**Line 4:** Reload the CMYK from RAM, delete CYK, leaving M, then load 3 empty black channels. We now have M, Black, Black, Black on our stack. Swap order to Black, M, Black, Black. Tell IM the 4 images on our stack are CMYK channels and combine them and write as `"M.jpg"`. Clean up.

**Line 5:** Reload the CMYK from RAM, delete CMK, leaving Y, then load 3 empty black channels. We now have Y, Black, Black, Black on our stack. Swap order to Black, Black, Y, Black. Tell IM the 4 images on our stack are CMYK channels and combine them and write as `"Y.jpg"`. Clean up.

**Line 6:** Load the CMYK from RAM. Delete CMY, leaving Black, save as `"K.jpg"`.

That gives this:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark, it does improve the performance. However `K.jpg` gives output with other colors as well. Other threes are correct

Comment: I have added the results I get. To my mind, they look like the correct colour separations for that input image - though I am no expert on print technology. Maybe you could click `edit` under your question and paste in anything that is different. Also, which version of ImageMagick are you on? I am using v7.0.8.

Comment: Yes, your images are correct. I am using ImageMagick 6.7.7-10

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mark Setchell. Your question is not very clear.

If you want to find the CMYK color equivalent for any pixel in your RGB input, then you can do the following, for example, for pixel (10,10). Here I use the ImageMagick special rose: image. But you can put any real image (image.suffix) in place of rose:. For real images, do not include the final colon.

```
convert rose: -colorspace CMYK -format "%[pixel:u.p{10,10}]\n" info:

cmyk(0,28,53,183)
```

If you want the whole image or any part of it to display CMYK values then use txt: output. For example, here is the top left 2x2 section of the rose: image.

```
convert rose:[2x2+0+0] -colorspace CMYK txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 2,2,65535,cmyk
0,0: (0,1365,4096,53199)  #000510CF  cmyk(0,5,16,207)
1,0: (0,2621,5243,52685)  #000A14CD  cmyk(0,10,20,205)
0,1: (0,1394,4183,53456)  #000510D0  cmyk(0,5,16,208)
1,1: (0,1365,4096,53199)  #000510CF  cmyk(0,5,16,207)
```

If you are trying to separate out each C,M,Y,K channel as individual images, then your first command does just that:

```
convert IMG_1732.jpg -colorspace CMYK -negate -separate IMG_1732-sep.jpg
```

Each resulting image, IMG_1732-sep-0.jpg, IMG_1732-sep-1.jpg, IMG_1732-sep-2.jpg, IMG_1732-sep-3.jpg represents the corresponding negated (inverted) C,M,Y,K channel. No need for any further processing. ImageMagick identify will say they are grayscale, but the values represent inverted C,M,Y,K for each image.

Note that any single channel image, will show in ImageMagick 6 as 3 identical channels. In ImageMagick 7, then are single grayscale channels.

Also note that -combine would need 3 or 4 input images to recombine back to RGB or CMYK. So I am not sure what your other commands are trying to do.

Comment: Updated question. Please check